# Why set/update RecyclerView.Adapter inside NestedScrollView temporary freezing?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, freeze

I have NestedScrollView, which contains horizontal adapter and vertical adapter. When I set adapter or update adapter, it always temporary freeze (few seconds - with profile it takes longer) and it get worse when more items is added!

Here is CPU load, but I do not understand why it is happening, what I can do better.

[image]

My code for adapter is pretty normal:

```
adapter = new Adapter(data);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any idea what could be wrong or how make this hierarchy better?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_01">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomMenu"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white_01"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/gray_05"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textBestSeller"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray_01"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Nejprodávanější" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rc1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white_01"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/cardOrder"
                            layout="@layout/shared_card_two_lines"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/cardFilter"
                            layout="@layout/shared_card_two_lines"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Nalezeno 325 produktů"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            tools:text="Nalezeno 325 produktů" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="Zrušit všechny filtry"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue_01"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rc2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/loading_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/retry_layout"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
        layout="@layout/shared_bottom_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_menu_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note1: First linear layout has reason, it is "generic" view which contains contents.

Note2: I am trying achive similar behaviour as GearBest has on homepage (scroll down). For them it seem to work well, so it is doable.

Adapter which still freezing:

```
public class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ProductItem> items;

    public SomeAdapter(List<ProductItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: After simplify fragment to this, problem is still there. It seems that for some reason combination of inflated layout and RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView cause the freeze. I continue searching.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: If you put something that can recycle into a scroll view it won't recycle at all. It will layout everything (and that will cause lag). Scroll view just provides a window into a long laid out view hierarchy. On top of that having a RelativeLayout as root is inefficient on its own. Use FrameLayout instead. Alignment to bottom and center can be done using gravity.

Comment: It would be interesting what `List<ProductItem> items` is and what `R.layout.item` is.

Comment: @Eugen, s..t, you are right. It seem all this is bad idea. So maybe I should inflate item one by one into scrollview, but I am not sure that it is also good idea :(

Comment: RecyclerView can hold different types of items. A header, n items and a footer for example. Ditch the scroll view and explore this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout hierarchy is pretty deep, and looking at your adapter, which does nothing, probably it takes long, because it has to measure everything. See https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#common-jank

The page also tells you how to record and debug the problem.

Judging from your fairly simple layout, that is expressed with *many* LinearLayouts I think you can do better using [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) also see [usage of ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/). As stated in [solutions](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#layout).

On a second look at your layout I see a `RelativeLayout` a `NeatedScrollView`and a `LinearLayout` (seen from the layouts root), that seem to serve no purpose. I suggest you delete them. (This is judging from your screenshot, as the layout you provided has a different structure.)

Comment: You may be right, but idea behind layout is to have root layout (relative layout), and child layouts as parts, where only one is always visible based on data/error state and yes, there is also one extra layout for bottom menu. Just saying to explain, why it is so "complex", becuase it should be generic for all fragments. I will try different layout. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think it is a better design if every Fragment has its own layout, that makes things faster and simpler, but of cause, in then end it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it would be better, if client wouldn´t ask for this :) But he did and now we must to do it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

After some research only working solution is to remove NestedScrollView and put EVERYTHING inside one recycler view and handle all as different types of view holders inside adapter.